# How to query distinct rows for every but one fields in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have a table like

```
A int,
B int,
C timestamp
```

and there are multiple rows where B and C are same but A is different. How can select one of the rows only (with any of A values) per each (B, C) unique pair in QuestDB?

If I had window function support I would

```
select A, B, C from (
select A, B, C,
 row_number() OVER (partition by B, C) as rownum
from tbl) temp
where temp.rownum = 1
```

but unfortunately window functions are not supported in QuestDB

Answer (score 1):

You can group by column you want to keep distinct and select `first()` on columns you want to choose random value from, like this

```
select first(A) as A, B, C
from tbl
```

`Group by` is not needed in QuestDB, it will figure out automatically that grouping is by B,C